# Is there a way to assign an ES5.1 class an anonym function?

Tags: javascript, antlr4, ecmascript-5

I was trying to implement ANTLR4 for a project that i'm working on and I created a Python3 parser for JavaScript by using the ANTLR4 tool. The problem is that when I try to run the code, the following error is raised:
[TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGqY0.png)

```
TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

The piece of code is the following:
[Assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql6Z6.png)

```
      let old_lexer = Python3Lexer;
      Python3Lexer = function () {
        old_lexer.apply(this, arguments);
        this.reset.call(this);
      }
```

Python3Lexer is a class.

I am using ANTLR 4.9.2 and ECMAScript 5.1 (but I don't really know if this one is running, maybe it is the default version).

I don't really understand what does that assignment mean and also I don't really know if it can be written on some other way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include relevant code snippets in your question rather than include external images.

Comment: @WiktorZychla thank you, I already added the code, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: How is `Python3Lexer` created? Is it a JS class?

Comment: @yccteam I think it is a JS class but the implementation uses ES (I'm not very familiarized with ES :( but the documentation of ANTLR4 says that it uses ES5.1). The declaration is as follows:
export default class Python3Lexer extends antlr4.Lexer {
     ..
     constructor(input) {
           ...
      let old_lexer = Python3Lexer;
      Python3Lexer = function () {
...
      }
           ..
    Python3Lexer.prototype.emitToken = function(token) {
            this._token = token;
            this.token_queue.push(token);
          };
           ..
    }
    ..
}

Comment: @Daltimus
Do you mean that the code is transpiled into ES5.1?
It might be that the `class` syntax is transpiled to something like:
`const Python3Lexer = function() {}`.
Do you have access to the transpiled code?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the code is generated with the ANTLR tool and I selected JavaScript as the output language. Everything in the code is generated by ANTLR and it says that works with ES5.1. I have access to the full code where the python3lexer is defined because it is the output of the ANTLR tool, it is into a file named ___Python3Lexer.mjs___

Answer (score 0):

Using ANTLR 4.9.x, the JavaScript target generates EcmaScript 6 source code and must be transpiled to EcmaScript 5 ([Documentation for the JavaScript target](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md) recommends using WebPack and has instructions for using it.)  The JavaScript runtime has a webpack.config.js to help out.  This is necessary for output that will run under an EcmaScript 5.x runtime.  (`class`, `let`, etc. are all ES6 specific).

Comment: Thank you so much @Mike!
I will try this way. I didn't know the concept of "transpiled", I am new with this.
I'm very grateful that you share your knowledge to me :D.